# rails webpacker error: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'logo.svg' in '/home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/packs'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, webpacker

I have an error running `rails webpacker:compile` on production server (Ubuntu server). Everything worked well before and everything works fine on my local computer (OSX)

- My rails version: **5.2.4.3**
- My ruby version - **2.6.6**
- My werpacker version - **gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.1'**

But :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'logo.svg' in '/home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/packs'
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:925:10
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213:14
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:25:1)
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:26:1)
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ModuleKindPlugin.js:30:40
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:14:1)
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:30:14
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:25:1)
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:14:1)
    at /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:25:1)
resolve 'logo.svg' in '/home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/packs'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /home/deploy/clotho/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/packs)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript
        using description file: /home/deploy/clotho/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /home/deploy/clotho/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/logo.svg)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/logo.svg doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/logo.svg.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/logo.svg.js doesn't exist
            .sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/logo.svg.sass doesn't exist
            .scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/logo.svg.scss doesn't exist
            .css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/logo.svg.css doesn't exist
            .module.sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/logo.svg.module.sass doesn't exist
            .module.scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/logo.svg.module.scss doesn't exist
            .module.css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/logo.svg.module.css doesn't exist
            .png
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/logo.svg.png doesn't exist
            .svg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/logo.svg.svg doesn't exist
            .gif
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/logo.svg.gif doesn't exist
            .jpeg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/logo.svg.jpeg doesn't exist
            .jpg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/logo.svg.jpg doesn't exist
            as directory
              /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/logo.svg doesn't exist
      /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/packs/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/deploy/clotho/app/javascript/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/deploy/clotho/app/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/deploy/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules
        using description file: /home/deploy/clotho/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /home/deploy/clotho/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/logo.svg)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/logo.svg doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/logo.svg.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/logo.svg.js doesn't exist
            .sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/logo.svg.sass doesn't exist
            .scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/logo.svg.scss doesn't exist
            .css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/logo.svg.css doesn't exist
            .module.sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/logo.svg.module.sass doesn't exist
            .module.scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/logo.svg.module.scss doesn't exist
            .module.css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/logo.svg.module.css doesn't exist
            .png
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/logo.svg.png doesn't exist
            .svg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/logo.svg.svg doesn't exist
            .gif
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/logo.svg.gif doesn't exist
            .jpeg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/logo.svg.jpeg doesn't exist
            .jpg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/logo.svg.jpg doesn't exist
            as directory
              /home/deploy/clotho/node_modules/logo.svg doesn't exist
```

This is my **webpacker.yml** file:

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: ['app/javascript/images', 'app/javascript/fonts']

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

This is my **webpack/development.js** file:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

This is my **webpack/production.js** file

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

This is my **webpack/environment.js** file:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

module.exports = environment
```

This is my **app/javascript/packs/application.js** file:

```
import "controllers"
const images = require.context('../images', true)
const fonts = require.context('../fonts', true)
```

Comment: Do you have an explicit import for 'logo.svg' somewhere? What does that line look like? Maybe in one of your JS controllers files? If so, where does 'logo.svg' live on the filesystem?